# Calling a web service from Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, security, authentication

What is the best way to add authentication / security while calling Web service from javascript ?
I want my web services should only get called from my application , anyone else should not be able to access my web service by copying web service URL into browser.

From the first few answers it seems like its next to impossible.
So what should I reply to my client as he is unaware of word impossible ?

~Ajinkya.

Comment: Salt, token, password? Can you explain more about how you're accessing the 'services'?

Comment: @Calumn: I am using my web service for YUI autocomplete.I just provide my web service URL to YUI  autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using the synchroniser token pattern so that the service can only be consumed with a piece of data known to the page which loads the service reference. There's an example of doing this with a web service in [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 5: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-5.html). This should achieve what you're after.

Comment: Sounds great. Will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If you allow a client to access your webservice from JavaScript, the client will always be able to do that. You can only reduce access by using some kind of constraint, like a Token that needs to be sent along with the request to authenticate it. You might even turn it into a one-time token. But this will create new problems (e.g. what happens if the answer gets lost. The client javascript cannot rerun the query).

Comment: @nfecher : Is there any by which we can prevent anyone from accessing service by copying web service URL into browser ?

Comment: No, not really. Besides: Because you allow the client to access the webservice at all, any such prevention will only be [snake oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does it mean that web services which are used through JAva script are always accessible to all ?

Comment: Within the limits that I stated in my answer, I would say: Yes.